# Prev() and next() while looping through a collection of objects in PHP

Tags: php, object, collections

So we all know that when iterating through a PHP array using foreach, the previous index can be accessed using prev() and the next index using next(). in my case, I am iterating through a  collection of objects and rendering there respective properties in my programming block.

Now I need to compare the current objects property with that of the previous object's property. Essentially prev() would suffice if it was an array, but I am at sea trying to do the same with PHP.

Tips please!

Thanks,
Parijat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$old = null;
foreach ( $objects as $object ) {
    if ( $old && $old->property == $object->property ) {
        foo();
    } else {
        bar();
    }
    $old = $object;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, got the solution earlier, but you are spot on with this!